# Webpack: modify default assets path location

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-cli

I have a Vue app which uses Webpack for minimizing the code.

Is there a way to parse the chunks and modify the base path from which webpack loads the assets?

Eg by default webpack loads assets from "/js" or "/css", etc. Due to server configuration I need it to load them from "/vue_dist/js" or "/vue_dist/css"

How could I do that?

Comment: Are you using Vue CLI or do you manage your Webpack config yourself ?

Comment: @MichalLevý  Vue CLI

Comment: https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#publicpath

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `publicPath` configuration prop provided by [Vue CLI](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#publicpath). Do not `publicPath` with [Webpack's](https://webpack.js.org/guides/public-path/) `output.publicPath`. These two are different.

In your `vue.config.js`, you can override the `publicPath` property as shown:

```
module.exports = {
  publicPath: `vue_dist`,
  
  // other config...
}
```

However, if you need more control over public path, then you must eject the configuration and then use Webpack's advanced public path.

> Note vue-cli@3 - With version 3, you should never have to eject the Webpack configuration. It addresses almost all the needs of custom configurations.

Comment: Thanks! As sidenote, others may find https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#assetsdir useful as well!